# Is there a way to have a virtual directory in iis 7 point to another domain?

Tags: iis, subdomain, rewrite, forwarding

Let us say I have two subdomains: http://content.mydomain.com and http://app.mydomain.com.

http://content.mydomain.com is pointing at a different server than http://app.mydomain.com is.  Is there a way to get a url of http://app.domain/content to point to http://content.mydomain.com without the url in the browser changing to the subdomain?

I am trying to get this to work in IIS 7 / 6 and am having issues.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you tried exploring http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/734/url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As Vivek commented you need to use URL Re-Writing for this, and use a technique called a "Reverse Proxy".

If IIS 7 is your first machine, then you have the options of:

- [IIS ReWrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)
- [ISAPI ReWrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

If IIS6 is your first machine, then you only have the option of  [ISAPI ReWrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).

The exact methods differ depending on your rewriting method, so choose one and then do a search on exactly how to do it.